# Intersection of the derived subgroup with a cyclic group

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups, derived-subgroup

Let $G$ be a group and $G'$ be the derived subgroup. Let $C=\langle c \rangle $ be a cyclic subgroup of $G$. Is it true that the intersection $H=G'\cap C$ is trivial?

I was thinking that if $g\in H$, then $g\in C$ and thus $g=c^{k}$, for some $k\in \mathbb{Z}$. Therefore, if  $f$ is the homomorphism from $G$ to the abelianization $\bar{G}$ of $G$, then $f(g)=c^{k}$ and thus is not trivial. Hence since $\ker f=G'$ we have a contradiction.

Is this idea correct or is there a case where $f(g)$ can be trivial in the abelianization?

Comment: No, this is not true. A simple counterexample is to take a case where $G'$ is nontrivial, let $c\neq e$ be an element in $G'$, and let $C=\langle c\rangle$. For example, $\langle (123)\rangle\cap (S_3)' = \langle (123)\rangle$. $f(g)=c^k$ does not make sense. $c$ lives in $G$, not in $\overline{G}$. You have $f(g) = \overline{f(c)^k}$, and you have no reason to think it is not trivial.

Comment: I am a little confused. If $c$ is a generator of $G$ then I can consider $\bar{G}$ to be the group with the same presentation as $G$ with the additional commutative relations. Then can I consider $f(g)=c^{k}$ as an element in $\bar{G}$?  The epimorphism between these two presentations maps the generators to themselves right?

Comment: No one said $c$ was a generator of $G$. If $c$ were a generator of $G$, then $G$ would be cyclic, and $G'$ would be trivial, and the question would be silly: the intersection of the trivial subgroup with any subgroup is of course trivial. If you mean that $c$ is part of a generating set of $G$, again this is superfluous: every element can be made part of a generating set of any group. But none of this matters. The element $c$ is **not** an element of $G/G'$; the corresponding element is the coset $cG'$, so $f(g)$ is not $c^k$, it is $(cG')^k = c^kG'$.

Comment: The reason you are confused is that you are treating two presentations of two distinct groups as if they were taking place in the same group. They don't. You can write $S_3$ as $\langle c,s\mid c^3=s^2=1, scs=c^{-1}\rangle$; and you can write $C_2$ as $\langle c,s\mid c^3=s^2=1, scs=c^{-1}, cs=sc\rangle$. But this is confusing: the map sending the $s$ in $S_3$ to $s\in C_2$, and $c\in S_3$ to $c\in C_2$ is of course a well-defined map, but the fact that $c^2\neq e$ in $S_3$ does not mean that $c^2\neq e$ in $C_2$; in fact, the $c\in C_2$ is trivial. (cont)

Comment: (cont) Which is why you shouldn't do that. In any case, I gave you an explicit and easy to check counterexample to your argument, so you can just try running your argument through that example to pinpoint exactly where your thinking went wrong... which is where you confuse the element $(123)\in S_3$ with its image in $S_3/(S_3)'$, and then assert that if the image of $(123)^k$ is trivial in $(S_3)/(S_3)'$ then it must be because $(123)^k$ was trivial in $S_3$. That's just not true.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking exactly that with these two presentations. Thank you.